# React Native platform specific import only works with relative paths

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a platform specific component split into 2 files:

```
src/components/Foo/Foo.android.tsx
src/components/Foo/Foo.ios.tsx
```

I want to import it in a file:

```
src/screens/Login.tsx
```

using:

```
import Foo from "components/Foo/Foo"
```

Non-platform specific files can be imported that way because I have setup this custom `tsconfig` for my project:

```
"paths": {                                /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
  "*": ["src/*"],
  "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
},
```

However RN bundler does not find the file. I can only import it using relative paths like this:

```
import Foo from "../../components/Foo/Foo"
```

I already tried to change my `@components` paths config to:

```
"@components/*": ["src/components/*", "src/components/*.android", , "src/components/*.ios"],
```

without success.

Any idea why the RN bundler is not able to find the import using `components` import path notation?